# NPM Start wont work on my angular project

Tags: angular

I've installed node modules by running `npm install`. When I run `npm start` on my project, I get the following error:

```
tcm@0.0.0 start
ng serve

Workspace extension with invalid name (defaultProject) found.
Option "browserTarget" is deprecated: Use 'buildTarget' instead.
****************************************************************************************
This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!
****************************************************************************************
file:///D:/Halo_Flights/haloflights_new/haloflights_new/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-ILV5JRA3.js:3427
import { ArrowFunctionExpr, LiteralArrayExpr, LiteralExpr as LiteralExpr2, literalMap, WrappedNodeExpr as WrappedNodeExpr3 } from "@angular/compiler";
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'ArrowFunctionExpr' not found. The requested module '@angular/compiler' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from '@angular/compiler';
const { ArrowFunctionExpr, LiteralArrayExpr, LiteralExpr: LiteralExpr2, literalMap, WrappedNodeExpr: WrappedNodeExpr3 } = pkg;

    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:132:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:214:5)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:431:15)
    at async readTsconfig (D:\Halo_Flights\haloflights_new\haloflights_new\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\read-tsconfig.js:48:54)
    at async configureI18nBuild (D:\Halo_Flights\haloflights_new\haloflights_new\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\i18n-options.js:125:22)
    at async generateI18nBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (D:\Halo_Flights\haloflights_new\haloflights_new\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:66:36)
    at async setup (D:\Halo_Flights\haloflights_new\haloflights_new\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\builders\dev-server\webpack-server.js:96:34)

Node.js v20.10.0
```

I've tried updating node modules, deleting package-lock.json file, and reinstalling node modules. Nothing is working and it keeps on showing me that error.

Comment: Please post your errors as code and not as pictures.

Comment: @TaherEl-hares i've added the error